# Is It Possible to Upload Certain Attachment Files To A Remote Server

Tags: uploads, media-library, cdn, pdf

#### My Situation

I'm developing a book-store WordPress website where you can purchase and download books in PDF format. I don't want to use the local space for file storage (the host provider offers cheaper solutions for "download servers").

---

#### What I want to achieve

Every time my client tries to upload a new book to the website through media library upload feature, WordPress can detect that it's a PDF file and automatically upload it to the *Download Server* and save that URL (e.g. books.mywebsite.com/books/novel/the-new-book.pdf ) into the database along with it's attachment data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can think of is about using APIs from also popular hosting services like **[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)**.

If you look at the documents it’s pretty easy to upload, list and delete files. I’m pretty sure you can do the same with other dozens of similar services.

The WP API will do the *REST* (LOL)... Read more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Comment: Yup thanks for your answer, I've found some similiar plugins that were doing the same.
At first I thought I have to tackle with media window itself but then I found out you have to add your custom tab to upload panel and make an applet for your custom upload solution.
Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: Always welcome.